# CSS3 transform issue in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got a problem. I have made my sliding menu with CSS3 transform but unfortunatly IE doesnt support that? Does anyone know if there is a fix for it somehow?

It starts out with having this as default:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0); 
-ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
```

And with a javascript click event i add this:

```
$('.MobilMenuContent').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0, 0)', '-moz-transform', 'translate(0, 0)', '-ms-transform', 'translate(0, 0)', '-o-transform', 'translate(0, 0)', 'transform', 'translate(0,0)');
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the transform? It's impossible to come up with a comparable result without knowing what you're currently doing.

Comment: I've just edited the post, so you can seewhat i'm doing ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i see [[ HERE ]](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hkwli) everything is OK!
What do you mean it's not working?
Your question is not clear enough!

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background: #ccc;

  -moz-transform: translate(100px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(100px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0);
  transform: translate(100px, 0);

  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    '-moz-transform': 'translate(0, 0)',
    '-ms-transform': 'translate(0, 0)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'translate(0, 0)',
    'transform': 'translate(0, 0)'
  })
});
```